# How to tell QT creator to parse .pro file when I build after changing it?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm using qt 5.3 under windows 7. Every time I edit the .pro file I need to clean up Makefile file under output/building folder to make it re-parse the changed pro file. I want it automatically detect the change when I hit build or run.

Is there some config I miss-set?

Comment: Any reason not to accept pixelgrease's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways to re-parse the .pro file:

- Right-click the project name in the Project pane (the topmost item) and select **Run qmake**
- Click the **Build/Run qmake** menu option
- Edit the .pro file, press Ctrl-S, and let Qt Creator automatically reparse it

It sounds like the third option is what you want and it's not working for you. It has traditionally been flakey and I never rely on it -- I use the first technique, right-clicking the Project and choosing **Run qmake**.